# Java8 Integer Stream Vs IntStream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

With the following code I am getting below compilation error. I also tried using input as List of Integer instead of int[] and with that it is working fine. It is also working fine if I use boxed().

My question really is does it has to be Integer stream instead if Int Stream and whats the deal with the error message "bad return type in lambda expression int[] cannot be converted to int"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = {1,2,3,4};

    List<int[]> result1 = Arrays.stream(numbers).flatMap(chara -> Arrays.stream(numbers)
            .map(operand -> new int[]{1, 2})).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

> Error:(13, 49) java: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda
>   expression
>       int[] cannot be converted to int Error:(13, 66) java: method collect in interface java.util.stream.IntStream cannot be applied to
>   given types;   required:
>   java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer
>   found: java.util.stream.Collector>   reason: cannot infer
>   type-variable(s) R
>       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Comment: what you want to achieve with your code?

Comment: well `map` expects an `int` as a return value not `int[]`. anyhow, your code doesn't make much sense to be honest. what exactly do you want to achieve here?

Comment: if `numbers` were a `List<Integer>` as you suggest then yes it would compile but I still don't see the need of all this when you can get the same result with `Stream.generate(() -> new int[]{1, 2})
                 .limit(numbers.size() * numbers.size())
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());`....

Comment: Sorry for confusing code. I will be more careful next time. I was just playing with a code out of a Java8 book and got confused here. I have now marked @Aominè answer as accepted answer. Thanks

Comment: @AnujJain don’t be sorry. It’s part of the learning experience. I was making silly mistakes a year and a half ago when I started learning Streams ^_^. Just make sure next time you post a question that you’re able to reply to questions on the comments section early on :). All the best!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I also tried using input as List of Integer instead of `int[]` and
>   with that it is working fine. It is also working fine if I use boxed()

So, that essentially means you've tried:

```
List<int[]> result1 = numbers.stream() 
                             .flatMap(chara -> numbers.stream()
                             .map(operand -> new int[]{1, 2}))
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

given numbers is a `List<Integer>`.

and:

```
List<int[]> result1 = Arrays.stream(numbers)
                            .boxed()
                            .flatMap(chara -> Arrays.stream(numbers).boxed()
                            .map(operand -> new int[]{1, 2}))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

given numbers is a `int[]`.

Yes, this does compile **but** this is not readable at all and there is definitely a better approach to generate the same result (shown later in the post).

As for the compilation errors, that's because of `Arrays.stream(numbers)` generates an `IntStream` and you're trying to `map` to a reference type (`int[]`) instead of primitive `int` which the function to `IntStream#map` expects. even if you were to solve that problem by doing `Arrays.stream(numbers).boxed()..` there would still be another problem down the line.

What your code pretty much does is this:

```
Stream.generate(() -> new int[]{1, 2})
      .limit(numbers.length * numbers.length)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, numbers.length * numbers.length)
         .mapToObj(n -> new int[]{1, 2})
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but in a more *idiomatic*, *readable* and *efficient* way.

Comment: Why `rangeClosed(1, numbers.length * numbers.length)` instead of `range(0, numbers.length * numbers.length)`? Another alternative is `List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(numbers.length * numbers.length, new int[]{ 1, 2}));   list.replaceAll(int[]::clone);`

Comment: @Holger There’s no reason not to. Just a matter of preference in this specific case.